# Why is a GeometryDrawing displayed on Canvas with clipped coordinates?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following simple code  that draws rectangle

```
    <Canvas Name="MainImageLayer" >
        <Image >
            <Image.Source >
                <DrawingImage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" >
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing >                            
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        <Pen Brush="#FF1acc33" Thickness="1" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush>Red</SolidColorBrush>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="300,480,287,83" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>

                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>                
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
```

The result looks like this - note that the rectangle is in **(0,0)**, even that the Rect is defined as

```
<RectangleGeometry Rect="300,480,287,83" />
```

[image]

I want it to start at **(300,480)**, like that:

[image]

I can achieve that by inspecting my **DrawingImage** and doing :

```
            <Canvas.Top>300</Canvas.Top>
            <Canvas.Left>480</Canvas.Left>
```

But isn't there a better way, considering the fact that this data is encoded into the **Geometry**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you have all of your geometry wrapped in an 'Image' object.  By default, the .Height and .Width properties of an Image object are set to 'Auto', and the .Stretch property is set to 'Uniform'.  This guarantees that your rectangle will always appear in the top left corner of your Canvas.

If you really need to encapsulate your geometry in an 'Image' object (which I would caution you not to do) you will need to set the Margin of your Image object to 300,480,0,0. in order to get your rectangle to appear where you want it.  This is required because of the way an 'Image' object handles its contents.

An Image object does not behave like a Canvas object, even if it is inside one.

Unless there is some overwhelming reason to keep the Image object, you will have much better success if you discard the Image and draw directly on the Canvas.

**EDIT**

*Why should an Image object not be used in this case?*
An Image object is primarily used for displaying...well, images, like bitmaps and such.  It is not suited for drawing geometry in it at a specific location (and size).  Like most WPF controls, it is what I would call a 'relative' control, meaning it is well suited for automatically resizing and positioning itself in relation to both its contents and its parent.  A Canvas on the other hand is an example of an 'absolute' control.  Its entire reason for existence is to allow content to be drawn upon it in an exact location with an exact size.  Adding an Image inside a Canvas and then drawing the geometry inside the Image just adds an unnecessary layer of complexity between the Canvas and the geometry that needs to be drawn.

*How can the geometry be added directly?*
One of the easiest ways would be to use the Path object given in Clemens' answer.  Just replace your entire Image object and all its contents with the 5 lines of that Path and your rectangle will appear exactly where it should be.  You can also do it with a single line and a Rectangle object:

```
<Rectangle Height="83" Width="287" Margin="300,480,0,0" Stroke="#FF1acc33" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red" />
```

but I would recommend the Path since it contains the size **and** position of the rectangle in one set of numbers.  The Path also allows you much more flexibility if you are working with shapes other than rectangles.

Comment: The rectangle object is an overkill. I rather use geometries, especially due to the fact that (1) They can be frozen - means they can be shared across threads, (2) They can define a region for hit testing - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx#wcpsdk_graphics_geometry_geometryandshapes. But, anyhow, thanks again for your great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the DrawingImage (or the GeometryDrawing?) is somehow adjusted to its visible rectangle. Anyway, wouldn't this be a much simpler solution, instead of Image?

```
<Path Stroke="#FF1acc33" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red">
    <Path.Data>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="300,480,287,83" />
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

You can also add another non-empty GeometryDrawing that covers (0,0) (e.g. a RectangeGeometry with Rect="0,0,1,1") with a transparent brush to the DrawingGroup.

EDIT: As i understood, the DrawingImage is adjusted to Drawing.Bounds

Comment: Thanks, it might be helpful to someone, but it is not what I asked for.

Comment: Andrey, what about adding another non-empty GeometryDrawing that covers (0,0) (e.g. a RectangeGeometry with Rect="0,0,1,1") with a transparent brush to the DrawingGroup?

Comment: Actually that is a good idea. Kind of ugly, but will do the work (+1)