# How do I prevent WPF from cropping my vector graphics?

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

I have an SVG graphic, which is a 264x264 square in the center of a 400x400 viewbox, and that 68 pixels of padding around the square is an important part of the image, I want that to show up in WPF. I'm using a library to convert the SVG drawing into a WPF DrawingImage, and the output after I've crammed it into a page to preview it looks like this:

```
<Page x:Class="Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400"
Title="Page1">

<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:svg="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/runtime/">
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        <DrawingGroup>
                                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFAAFFAA">
                                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                        <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="10" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" />
                                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="68,68,264,264" />
                                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,400" />
                                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                            <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                            </DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                        </DrawingGroup>
                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,400" />
                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
</Page>
```

The resulting image is a square that completely fills its container, instead of leaving some empty space around it like I want. How do I get WPF to preserve that space instead of cropping it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `DrawingImage`, empty space is ignored/cropped when rendering the `Image`. This post discusses the same problem: [Why is a GeometryDrawing displayed on Canvas with clipped coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822283/why-is-a-geometrydrawing-displayed-on-canvas-with-clipped-coordinates)

You can achieve what you want by drawing the empty space as a transparent 400x400 rectangle behind the green rectangle:

```
...
<DrawingGroup>
    <DrawingGroup.Children>

        <!-- Added transparent "spacer": -->
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="0,0,400,400" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>

        <!-- This was here before: -->
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFAAFFAA">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="10" 
                     StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="68,68,264,264" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
        ...
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
For those of you using the same conversion library (SharpVectors, New BSD license), it's fairly simple to modify its output to create these transparent rectangles for you. Inside the if statement starting in WpfSvgRendering.cs on line 140 (assuming sharpvectors-24484.zip is your source package), for every `drawGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry([some Rectangle instance]);`
add a `_drawGroup.Children.Insert(0, new GeometryDrawing() { Brush = Brushes.Transparent, Geometry = new RectangleGeometry([some Rectangle instance]) });` on the next line